# Save x amount of lines with StreamWriter and Console output

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a Windows (C#) command line program that redirects console output to a text file using StreamWriter. This works fine and all but I only ever need the last 100 lines of the log and I'm writing around 5 times a second to the log file, so you can imagine how big this file can possibly get. What I'd like to do is overwrite the file completely every 100 lines or so of the StreamWriter. Does anyone have an efficient way of doing this?

My current code (that is working) is:

```
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(
    string.Format("{0}/logs/{1}.txt", 
    baseDir, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")), 
    false, 
    Encoding.ASCII, 
    16384
);

streamWriter.AutoFlush = true;
var originalOut = Console.Out;
Console.SetOut(streamWriter);

// .. do my stuff and write lines...
Console.WriteLine("This is a test...");

// ..finished..
Console.SetOut(originalOut);
streamWriter.Dispose();
```

How to adapt this to overwrite the logs file every 100 lines?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why have I been downvoted? This is a genuine question asking for an efficient method of dealing with this.

Comment: `genuine question`? :)) Too much self-confidence?. Anyway, I can't see the inefficent implemantation.

Comment: Yes the code does work but it will write lines to the log file endlessly, I really only have a need for the last 100 lines, so I only want those 100 lines present in the log file. Hope that makes sense! :)

Comment: You can try CodeReview, a better Stack Exchange site. It's primarily for trimming down code or fixing code that already runs smoothly

Comment: @Daveo: Do you need to keep the last 100 lines that would have been written just before calling `Dispose`, or do you need the log file to contain the most recent 100 lines at any point in time during the operation?

Comment: @Douglas: I want the log file to only contain the most recent 100 lines at any point during the operation. Thank you. :)

Comment: That requirement might be very expensive, since for every new line you write, you'll need to shift an existing 99 lines backward, meaning you're effectively writing 100 times as many lines as you would if you just append. (That would not be strictly true for short lines due to disk block access, but will become an issue if your lines are long.) A reasonable compromise might be to store 100–200 lines, clearing the oldest 100 just when the 200 mark is reached.

Comment: That's true. I've decided the total file size for the log each day is 24mb, which I don't think impacts performance that much so I've just decided to continue as it currently is. Trying to only have the last 100 lines might just work out as too expensive as it is. If anyone does have a good idea though please feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for the suggestion I made in [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514367/save-x-amount-of-lines-with-streamwriter-and-console-output#comment32482952_21514367).

```
// Keeps most recent 100–200 lines.
List<string> cache = new List<string>();

while (true)
{
    // Create new writer, overwriting old file (if it already exists).
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(/* ... */))
    {
        // Write last 100 lines from cache.
        if (cache.Count > 0)
            streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cache));

        // Get next line and write it.
        string line = /* your implementation */
        streamWriter.WriteLine(line);

        // Append to cache.
        cache.Add(line);

        // If cache limit reached, we need to recycle.
        if (cache.Count == 200)
        {
            // Keep only most recent 100 lines.
            cache = cache.Skip(100).ToList();

            // Start a new iteration, causing the file to be overwritten.
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Cheers! I didn't handle date changes in my code (since I couldn't see how you addressed them in yours), but you'll probably need to implement some additional logic for them. Be careful that you clear the cache when starting to write a new day's log.